# How to change config dir of the telegram cli

Tags: telegram

I needed to change my config dir. Now its `config dir=[/root/.telegram-cli]` but I want to use another directory (not a root).

Could you help me with a way to change it?

Answer (score -1):

```
telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub -c telegram.config

create file - telegram.config:
    *default_profile = "main_prof";

    main_prof = {
        config_directory = "/usr/lib/tg";
                 };*
```

Comment: Code-only answers [are discouraged on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques/148274#148274) because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.